# ¿Cómo uso rest api en mi proyecto de asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

¿Cómo puedo usar rest api en mi proyecto de `asp.net` mvc? He estado viendo este tutorial [ResApi](http://www.genbetadev.com/formacion/haciendo-una-api-rest-en-1-hora-con-asp-net-web-api-ii)

Comment: Hola Gustavo, bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo darle una lectura a: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general si tienes servicio rest es porque vas a consumirlos mediante codigo cliente en javascript, la forma mas simple de hacerlo es por medio de `jquery` o `AngularJs`

El servicio rest devuelve `json` que usas para asignar al html que definas

[Implementing & Consuming ASP.NET WEB API from JQuery (MVC 4)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424461/Implementing-Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-from-JQuery)

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

[[ASP.NET Web API] Web API III – Consumiendo el servicio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn358432.aspx)

como observaras en los ejemplos usas $.ajax en donde puedes indicar los verbos GET, POST, DELETE, etc para realizar las acciones de la webapi expone